# Why is this question counted as "off topic"

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Why is this  question   counted  as  off topic?

[Unreasonable application of mathematics to the other areas](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/243030/unreasonable-application-of-mathematics-to-the-other-areas)

Comment: Instead of "off-topic", the question could also have been closed as a duplicate of [this question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/61408/examples-of-theorems-misapplied-to-non-mathematical-contexts).

Comment: @Stefan  No I say it is duplicaa but not off topic.